# How to add the same IAM role to assume_role_policy with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a role for the Grafana EC2 instance to allow it to read metrics from CloudWatch. I've faced this issue: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/19173, and it seems like I need to add these lines to the Trust relationship to fix it.

```json
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::[id-removed]:role/grafana",
          "arn:aws:sts::[id-removed]:assumed-role/grafana/GrafanaSession"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
```

So I'm wondering how to do it with Terraform. At the moment I'm playing with this version of terraform script:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
  version = "~> 2.0"
}

variable "aws_account_id" {
  type = string
  default = "account_id"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {  
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }

  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [
          "arn:aws:iam::${var.aws_account_id}:role/grafana",
          "arn:aws:sts::${var.aws_account_id}:assumed-role/grafana/GrafanaSession"
          ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "grafana" {
  name               = "grafana"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json
}
```

It fails with `MalformedPolicyDocument: Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"arn:aws:iam::[id-removed]:role/grafana"`

To make it work I have to comment the second statement block of `aws_iam_policy_document`, run terraform apply, then uncomment it and run terraform apply again, which is not a very convenient way to work with, as we run our terraform scripts from GitLab, so it means we have to commit without assumed roles, tag, deploy, commit with assumed roles, tag and deploy again :explode

Comment: Are you sure you really need "role/grafana" in there? It doesn't really make sense to me to allow a role to assume itself.

Comment: You can't add a non-existing role as a principle. So you can't create a role and at the same time refer it as a principle, as it does not exist yet. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Marcin, I'm thinking about how I can do it with terraform. Is it possible to create a resource and update it in the same module?

Comment: @bonzaster I'm not aware of a pretty way of doing this. But terraform allows you to run any code (e.g. aws cli) or invoke a lambda function. So you could always create the role properly, without the troublesome iam statement, and then use local-exect to run aws cli to update the iam role.

Comment: @Marcin oh, good idea, will take a look at it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @bonzaster No problem. Let me know how it will go:-)